# How do I display an object from an array based on timer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a music application and I'd like to display content from a specific object in an array based on a start and duration time. Here is an example of my data.

```
[
{
id: 1,
content: 'hello how are you',
start: 0,
duration: 10
},
{
id: 2,
content: 'hello Im fine',
start: 15,
duration: 10
},
{
id: 3,
content: 'hope you you have a great day',
start: 30,
duration: 10
}
]
```

So basically I will be using the currentTime property on the audio element, and based on this property I will display the appropriate message on content property. Currently I've been able to match the content start with the currentTime, but unable to figure out how to display over the duration. This is pretty much what I have:

```
const PodcastDetail = ({ podcast }) => {
    const [currentMarker, setCurrentMarker] = useState({});
}

  const handleMarker = (podcast) => {
        let marker = podcast.markers.find((mark) => {
            return mark.start  == currentTime;
        })
        setCurrentMarker(marker)
    }
```

As you can see I'm just returning the object from the array which matches the current time, however it disappears once the currentTime changes. I'd like to display that content throughout its duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however it disappears once the currentTime changes.

It's because you just change your state with a `null` (no object found) :)
You can basically do something like that:

```
const handleMarker = (podcast) => {
    let marker = podcast.markers.find((mark) => {
        return mark.start  == currentTime;
    })
    if (marker) setCurrentMarker(marker)
}
```

So if no marker match your `currentTime`, you don't update the state, so you leave the previous marker in your state

== EDIT ==

And if you want to use your `duration` you should change your condition to

```
const handleMarker = (podcast) => {
    let marker = podcast.markers.find((mark) => {
        return (currentTime >= mark.start) && (currentTime <= (mark.start + mark.duration));
    })
    setCurrentMarker(marker)
}
```

In this case I remove the condition to `setCurrentMarker` because you indeed want to set it at `null` if nothing matches the condition

Comment: Ok, looks like it'll solve one issue. But what about keeping the content displayed for the duration specified?

Comment: Well your `return mark.start  == currentTime;` is not valid, as it checks only the start. So you should use `duration` here also! Something like `currentTime <= (mark.start + mark.duration) && currentTime >= mark.start)` See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You should change the condition to check whether it is within the interval as well.

```
const handleMarker = (podcast) => {
  let marker = podcast.markers.find((mark) => {
    return (
      mark.start <= currentTime && currentTime <= mark.start + mark.duration
    );
  });
  setCurrentMarker(marker);
};
```

Comment: Thx to both. This solution appears to be what I needed. I had tried something like this previously but I think there was an issue with my return statement.